# How to change dropdown field function to buttons in privatemsg module

Tags: 6, privatemsg

I am using private message module.

In that there is a option to mark the messages as read and unread using drop down.

Here it looks like : http://drupal.org/node/709180

**Instead of that i need to place two buttons called "Mark as Read" and "Mark as Unread" and needs to perform the same action.**

How can i do it?

Any help will be grateful.

Thanks in adavnce...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by the  following way:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

switch ($form_id) {

    case 'privatemsg_list':

    // Removing Adding  Dropdowns and adding button for the "Mark as read" and "Mark as unread" function
    $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div style="display:none">';
    $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['mark as read'] = array(
      '#type'   => 'submit',
      '#value'  => t('Mark as Read'),
      '#weight' => 15,
    );

    $form['mark as unread'] = array(
      '#type'   => 'submit',
      '#value'  => t('Mark as UnRead'),
      '#weight' => 15,
    );

    $form['delete'] = array(
      '#type'   => 'submit',
      '#value'  => t('Delete'),
      '#weight' => 15,
    );
    break;
}
```

And it's done..

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `hook_privatemsg_thread_operations_alter(&$operations)` (unfortunately not documented but called in [_privatemsg_action_form()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.pages.inc/function/_privatemsg_action_form/6-2)) to change the mark as read and mark as unread operations to use a button, as does delete. They are defined in [privatemsg_privatemsg_thread_operations()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_privatemsg_thread_operations/6-2).

Something like this:

```
<?php
function yourmodule_privatemsg_thread_operations_alter(&$operations) {
  $operations['mark as read']['button'] = TRUE;
  $operations['mark as unread']['button'] = TRUE;
}
?>
```

Note: This requires Privatemsg 6.x-2.x

Comment: Could you make the answer in detail. As I am a newbie it's bit confusing..

Comment: I have no idea what kind of "details" you need. You seem to know about hooks and how to implement them or you wouldn't have been able to come up with your solution below. Your hook simply alters the end result,  my hook alters the data source on which the form is then built.

Comment: @@Berdir: Thanks for your reply.. But for your kind information i have tried the sample code given by you.. that doesn't works or may be i made some mistake on my code which i can't troubleshoot.. that's why i ask the answer in detail.

Comment: +1 for hook_privatemsg_thread_operations_alter(&$operations)